# Millisecond time difference from Calendar too big

Tags: java, timestamp

I'm trying to compare two millisecond values in Java. One from a calendar, and one from `System.currentTimeMillis()`. However, it seems the value from the calendar is always far larger than the one from `System.currentTimeMillis()` at the correct time.

To build the calendar, I'm parsing a date string in the format `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm` and putting it's consitutuent parts in to a calendar (try-catch omitted for brevity).

```
Calendar obCal = null;

//Exception here shows invalid format
DateFormat DF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
DF.parse(Date);

//Example string: 29/11/2011 16:30
String[] parts = Date.split("/");

obCal = Calendar.getInstance();
int Y = Integer.parseInt(parts[2].split(" ")[0]);
int m = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
int d = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
int H = Integer.parseInt(parts[2].split(" ")[1].split(":")[0]);
int M = Integer.parseInt(parts[2].split(" ")[1].split(":")[1]);

obCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, Y);
obCal.set(Calendar.MONTH, m);
obCal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, d);
obCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, H);
obCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, M);
obCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
obCal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

Inspecting the calendar after this shows me it is receiving the correct date and time. I then get the millisecond value since the epoch from `obCal.getTimeInMillis()` and store it as a number of seconds as a `long`

```
long stamp = obCal.getTimeInMillis() / 1000L;
```

When I reach the time represented by the date string, and compare the timestamp from the calendar to timestamp `System.currentTimeMillis()`, I find the former is far larger. The difference between the current time and the calendar time (`curTime-calTime`) is, usually, somewhere in the region of `-2,500,000`

What could be causing this?
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just use `Calendar#setTime(...)` ?

Comment: Why don't you use `obCal.setTime(DF.parse(date));`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Month is 0-based so when you do `obCal.set(Calendar.MONTH, m);` you're off by 1 month.

Comment: Thankyou! I've been staring at this problem for hours, and that's fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you missed that the Calendar API defines MONTH to be in range 0 to 11, while you parse it as 1 to 12. That makes a 30 * 86400 Second difference...